# Android Facebook login with Firebase forces authentication via facebook.com/devices

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication, facebook-login

I want to create facebook login in my Android Application which is connected with Firebase.
I followed the instruction in Firebase docs.
Right now login with Facebook is possible, but the only way to login is to go to facebook.com/devices and wright one-time code. Also, my app is not asking me if I want to chenge account to another one.

I want my application to read my facebook account from telephone and ask me if I want to log in to this account or log in using credentials.

[When I click "login with facebook" this is beeing showed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/co9II.jpg)

This is code which I wrote:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
[...]
    mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create()
    val facebookButton = findViewById<View>(R.id.facebook_register_button) as LoginButton

    facebookButton.setReadPermissions("email", "public_profile")
    facebookButton.registerCallback(mCallbackManager, object : FacebookCallback<LoginResult> {
        override fun onCancel() {//...}
        override fun onError(error: FacebookException?) {//...}
        override fun onSuccess(result: LoginResult) {
            handleFacebookAccessToken(result.accessToken)
        }
    })
}

private fun handleFacebookAccessToken(token: AccessToken) {
    val credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(token.token)
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this) {
                when {
                    it.isSuccessful -> updateUI(mAuth.currentUser)
                    else -> {
                        LoginManager.getInstance().logOut()
                        updateUI(it.exception)
                    }
                }
            }
}
```

I albo code meta-data and INTERNET permission in manifest file

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you logout current account?

Comment: I logout from firebase and using LoginManaget too, this is the code of logout button:
    mAuth.signOut()
    LoginManager.getInstance().logOut()

Comment: You only logout when signin issue.

Comment: No, I also have button for logout, as I wrote earlier

Comment: fun firebaseLogOut(view: View){
        mAuth.signOut()
        LoginManager.getInstance().logOut()
        startActivity(Intent(this, LoginActivity::class.java))
    }